# How to fix angular error TS2322 (using an ngFor (FileList))

Tags: angular

I fully understand that in angular we always need to pay attention to the type, but the error caused by this example is really incomprehensible.

I have a fileList, its type would be FileList, and when the user hasn't selected a file yet, the fileList certainly doesn't exist.

So in html I use ngIf to check if the fileList exists, and once it does, then ngFor loops it out.

**HTML**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fileList">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of fileList">
    {{ item.name }}
  </mat-list-item>
</ng-container>
```

**TS**

```
fileList?: FileList;
---
onFileSelected(event: Event) {
  const targrt  = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const files   = targrt.files as FileList;
  if ( files ) {
    this.fileList = files;
  }
}
```

However, it responds to this message.

> error TS2322: Type 'FileList' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Iterable | (Iterable & any[]) | (any[] & Iterable) | null | undefined'.

Please correct my mistake, how can I improve it? Thank any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs at the line where you have mentioned:

```
const files   = targrt.files as FileList;
```

It happens because [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) is not an Array, and does not inherit from an Array, but it does implement [the iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), so you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get it as an array OR you can convert it into an array type to use it for *ngFor purpose.

This method would help in this case. `Array.from(target.files)`

OR

```
[...target.files]
```

Improved code in your case:

```
fileList?: any[] = [];

onFileSelected(event: Event) {
  const targrt  = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  fileList = Array.from(targrt.files);
  // OR, you can also do this
  // fileList = [...targrt.files];
}


<ng-container *ngIf="fileList && fileList.length > 0">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of fileList">
    {{ item.name }}
  </mat-list-item>
</ng-container>
```

I hope it helps..!!

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you @PorkJackson for accepting my answer. Appreciate it. Tag me next time when you have more questions on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to array and use it in `*ngFor`

```
const fileList = Array.from(yourFileList)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was solved.